# PayPal setNoteToBuyer(String) - how to display the note in two lines

Tags: java, paypal

On Paypal express checkout page in the order customization section(left side on PayPal page) I want to show order delivery details as well.

I was not able to find a function to send delivery details; So I choose to display the order delivery details as a note to the buyer.

I am using the following function

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType::setNoteToBuyer(String)
```

But I want the note to showup in two lines.

Currently i am sending "Delivery Date" + "Delivery Time"

I want the note to look as shown below

Delivery Date

Delivery Time

I tried using:

```
"Delivery Date" + "/n" + "Delivery Time"
```

but it didn't work.

It showed on PayPal page as "Delivery Date  /n Delivery Time"

I have tried html break tag as well, it did not work.

Following is my code in java REST call

```
setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setNoteToBuyer("Delivery Date" + "Delivery Time");
```

-RK

Answer (score 0):

"Delivery Date" + **"/n"** + "Delivery Time"

I believe this should be "\n" for newline.

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputing it to the terminal or to a web app? You mentioned HTML.

You can try one of these two delimeters instead of `/n`:

- `\r\n` (Unix and Windows newlines)
- `<br />` (HTML line-break)

Comment: I sending this to PayPal via setExpressCheckout call to display on the buyer login page. I have inspected the element on their site using "inspect using Firebug" and found PayPal puts the string inside a div -  <div class="small secondary">Delivery Date &lt;br&gt; Delivery Time</div>; please notice how break html element got converted to &lt;br&gt;

Comment: Ah, I see. They're HTML-encoding it, which is a good security practice. I suggest you change your output entirely, then, and put something like: `"Delivery Date at Delivery Time" or something that doesn't use a newline in it.

Comment: Thank u , as suggested i have changed output entirely to "Delivery Date and Time:"

Comment: @RamyaKarri please accept this answer if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does HTML encoding of the Note field on the login page - order customization section.

Therefore we cannot have note in two lines.

In my example I modified the Note to say "Delivery Date and Time:" instead of

Delivery Date

Delivery Time

-RK